# Caldroid library calendar not showing all dates in landscape

Tags: android, calendar

I'm using [Caldroid](https://github.com/roomorama/Caldroid) library to display calendar as a dialog fragment. its working good but when in landscape mode the calendar is not showing all dates (last week is missing). see the pic:

[image]

I've checked the xml in the library for this view and its using view pager and i'm not understanding how to modify it. and one more doubt, how can i disable all dates from current date?

EDIT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/caldroid_white"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/calendar_title_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/calendar_left_arrow"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/left_arrow" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/calendar_month_year_textview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/calendar_right_arrow"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/calendar_left_arrow"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:textSize="22sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/calendar_right_arrow"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/right_arrow" />
</RelativeLayout>

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/weekday_gridview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="-15dp"
    android:numColumns="7"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >
</GridView>

<com.antonyt.infiniteviewpager.InfiniteViewPager
    android:id="@+id/months_infinite_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="-10dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: actually i've just used dialogCaldroidFragment class from the library.. so the xml from the lib is updated in question.

Answer (score 1):

(I'm Caldroid author)

The cell inside the calendar is square, hence in landscape mode and small layout, it doesn't have enough space. I don't have best solution for this mode, but there're a few things you could try:

- Do not display dialog title ("Select a date"). It will give more space for the calendar
- Set `SIX_WEEKS_IN_CALENDAR` in initial arguments to "false"
- Provide your custom cell that is not a square

Let me know what works best for you so I can improve the library, or even better send me a pull request :)

Comment: So what does setting SIX_WEEKS_IN_CALENDAR to false actually do? It just doesn't **force** the calendar to always show six full weeks, which is ofcourse the maximum a calendar will ever need to show to cover a full month.

I ask as I'm trying to compress the calendar down a little, in portrait and _not_ as a dialog. What would you suggest is the easiest / best way to achieve this?

Thanks for the library btw.

Comment: Calendar months can have 4, 5 or 6 weeks, which translate to 4, 5 or 6 rows in the caldroid. Setting SIX_WEEKS_IN_CALENDAR to true will show calendar with 6 rows, with redundant rows. Setting it to false force calendar to wrap to 4, 5 or 6 rows. If you want to compress the calendar, it's best to provide your custom cell.

Answer (score 1):

In InfiniteViewPager get rid of onMeasure method and replace calendar_view.xml content with the following one:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/caldroid_white"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/calendar_title_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/calendar_left_arrow"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:background="@drawable/left_arrow" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/calendar_month_year_textview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/calendar_right_arrow"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/calendar_left_arrow"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:textSize="21sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/calendar_right_arrow"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@drawable/right_arrow" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <GridView
        android:layout_below="@+id/calendar_title_view"
        android:id="@+id/weekday_gridview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
        android:numColumns="7"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >
    </GridView>

    <com.antonyt.infiniteviewpager.InfiniteViewPager
        android:layout_below="@+id/weekday_gridview"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/months_infinite_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```